# Relational Database designing

Tags: database-design, rdbms, modeling

I have the following tables

```
   CUSTOMER (cust_id (PK), name, phone)
   ADDRESS (add_id (PK), address, area)
   CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (cust_id, add_id) (composite PK) (Junction Table)
```

The above model enables one customer to have many addresses and one address to have many customers (many-to-many) (members of the same family).

I want to achieve the following in my model:

I want that a customer may have more than one phone number. For this I can make another table and have cust_id as a FK in that table but the address is also related to the new table (let's say "PHONE"). The phone number is the first piece of information that comes in the system. Then it is to be checked, if the no. already exists in the database, we pick up the customer information (address, name etc) and take his order. In case no cust_id is associated with it, then address is checked, if an address already exists then that number should be inserted in the "PHONE" table with appropriate 'cust_id' reference.

How will the data be added into the database. The two conditions need to be checked are:

1. No cust_id should exist referencing that no. in the CUSTOMER table.
2. The address should not exist in the ADDRESS table. If the address exists then there must be a cust_id related to it, we add a second phone number to the cust_id in this case.

I hope you understand the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, both of your conditions are going to create issues for you.

What if the NEW customer (new cust_id) resides at the same address, sharing the same phone number (think land line) as an existing customer?  Do you really want to potentially lose that customer because of a bad business/integrity rule?

How about if a customer (or many customers) are using a business address?
They all might share an address and a phone number.  Might or might not have different extensions.  Or if they are all using the same accounts payable office address/phone number?  How about if I am ordering something to be shipped to my friends house?

The phone number may have been able to be associated with an address years ago when we only had land lines, but mobile phones have changed this dynamic.

You would be better off scrapping the idea of a phone number being associated with an address and simply have the phone number being associated with a customer.
This will simplify your life.

You should be checking to see if the phone or address already exists.
You will need to define the business rules regarding how to handle a "duplicate".  But remember that these duplicates could be because of roommates, a recent move, a new phone account and potentially many other reasons.

You should also look into the idea of address_type and phone_type.

Comment: This is a food ordering system so if many people are using the same landline then it's perfectly fine. I just need the address associated with the no. Who orders does not really matter as long as the address is same. If the address is different then a customer can have many addresses anyway. The issue is how do I make a customer to have many numbers and the columns be generated dynamically as the number comes in.